# Modification with Paypal Extension in magento2

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to  use Paypal as the payment gateway in magento2.
Paypal doesn't support ZAR currency.
Is there any paypal extension for magento that will allow me to use ZAR currency.
Or What i have to do to change the core of the extension to achieve my goal.